# Which convention is better?

Tags: java

I was wondering which convention is better and clearer to read?

```
void someMethod() {
    if (!condition) {
        return;
    }

    // do some work
}
```

Or

```
void someMethod() {
    if (condition) {
        // do some work
    }
}
```

Comment: i think first is better

Comment: Voted to close, because it is primarily opinion based. One half will say this, the other half that.

Comment: In general, I think the second is better.

Comment: Well one that you type by intuition?Sometimes its easyer to just dont think about it too mutch!

Answer (score 4):

Depends on the name of the method. You don't want to do:

`if(!notEmpty())`

There is no preferable or better way to do it. Depends on the method name, logic..

Comment: Yes, I agree with you. But let's say both sound good. My question is which is more clearer? If all method execution depends on that condition is it better to put it in the first line with not condition and return or it's better to wrap the code in if condition method.

Comment: @Teodor Depends on many things.. For me, the second is clearer.. But it's only me.. There is no preferable way.. IMHO.

Comment: Okay, as I said I was just wondering because I caught my self to use both of these conventions. Thank you for your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure which you are referring to: checking the inverse of the condition or returning earlier. For the former is not hard and fast depends on which is more logical in the context and easier to read for the next person. For the latter returning earlier may improve efficiency

Answer (score 0):

Personally I prefer the former. Pedants will say that it is unstructured, but I would argue that it is a question of semantics.